# Find a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a holomorphic function $f(z,\bar{z})$ such that  $Argf(z)=xy \;mod\;2\pi$.
I'm trying to apply CRE, i.e if $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ , and by condition we have $tgArgf(z)=\frac{u}{v}$ i.e $u=vtgArgf(z)$. Then use CRE $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}tg(xy)+\frac{vy}{cos^2(xy)}=\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}$ and $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}=\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}tg(xy)+\frac{vx}{cos^2(xy)}=-\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}$. Then if we sum right-hand sides of this equations, we get $\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}-\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}=(\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}-\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}})tg(xy)$. Thus tg(xy)=1? So, in this case we have u=v and then $f(z)$ is a constant?

Comment: What does golomorphic mean? It's not a classic.

Comment: In addition to Arnaud's question, is $f=f(z)$ or $f= f(z, \bar z)$ or are you considering both?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier holomorphic*, it's a mistake.

Comment: @Thomas we considering both of this

Answer (score 1):

If it's holomorphic, it's a function of $z$ alone, because the Cauchy-Riemann equations mean $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$. But what do you think of $e^{z^2/2}$? Your equation $Argf(z)=xy \;mod\;2\pi$ implies a factor $e^{ixy}$, and $ixy$ is clearly the imaginary part of $z^2/2=(x^2-y^2)/2+ixy$.

Comment: How did you get this answer?

Comment: @Mathworld I've edited my answer. (actually, it was meant as a comment, but I often write it in the answer area, first, because it renders MathJax, so it happens every once in a while that I hit "post", accidentally.

Comment: One more question, $e^{\frac{z^2}{2}}$ is all function satisfying the condition $Argf(z)=xy \;mod\;2\pi$, right?

Comment: @Mathworld I don't know for sure, to be honest, but I think that's quite likely (up to a multiplicative constant, naturally). Because the logarithm of your $f$ has to be holomorphic (at least locally), and the real part is pretty much determined by the imaginary part by those same Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Thanks for answers!

Comment: @Mathworld You're welcome. Btw, I prefer upvotes to "thanks", but don't hurry with accepting an answer: you may get a better one by somebody else, later.